# Chronometers inside items on RecyclerView not seen by the users are not starting,

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created a recycler view witch updates itself with a collection of data on arbitrary times, I have a chronometer on display on each of those items, and in some instances those chronometers are to be started as soon as they get displayed, the prooblem is the chronometers that haven't been seen by the user are not starting until the user scrolls to them.

I'm using android-studio on a recyclerview using gridlayoutmanager.

I tried with

```
GridLayoutManager itemlistManager= new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),3);
itemlistManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(true);
itemlistManager.collectAdjacentPrefetchPositions(3,10,null,null);
```

But it isn't showing any difference

The expected behavior is to have all the chronometers ticking as soon as the view is created, but right now I have to scroll to the bottom to make the chronometers at the end of the list to start.

bindViewHolder

```
    @Override

 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolderData holder, final int position) {

        long sumtime=0,diferenceToSum=0;
       if(myConstants.chronometerFix){
           holder.myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
       }else{
        if(myList.get(position).getCronometerTimeSum()!=null&&!myList.get(position).getCronometerTimeSum().trim().isEmpty()){
               sumtime = myUtilities.string2milis(myList.get(position).getCronometerTimeSum());
           }
           if(myList.get(position).getMyItemState().equals("1")){
               if(myList.get(position).getCronometerStart()!=null&&!myList.get(position).getCronometerStart().trim().isEmpty()&&myList.get(position).getServerTime()!=null&&!myList.get(position).getServerTime().trim().isEmpty()){
                   diferenceToSum = myUtilities.datesCompareToMilis(myList.get(position).getCronometerStart(),myList.get(position).getServerTime());
               }
               holder.myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-sumtime-myConstants.myCronometerOffsetFinal-diferenceToSum);
holder.myChronometer.start();
           }else{
               holder.myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-sumtime);
           }
       }
        String temp =  myList.get(position).getName() +
                " / " +
                myList.get(position).getItemName() +
                " / " +
               myList.get(position).getPosition();
        holder.myNamePositionItem.setText(temp);
       holder.myPosition.setText(String.valueOf(myList.get(position).getPosition()));
        holder.myName.setText(myList.get(position).getMyName());
    }
```

Comment: Could you paste your `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s `bindViewHolder` implementation?

Comment: This is not an error - Views are not created unless they're seen. `ViewHolder`s are meant to display (or interact) with data only, not actively hold it. Moreover, as You scroll through, views that leave the viewport are actually reused and bound to other positions. My question is why do You need chronometers running for items that are not seen?

Comment: Pawel, i need the chronometers running because i need to know how long they have been in my device, regardless of the fact that i can see them or not